# Nested reference to `this` in ES6 classes

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

Take the following example;

```
class MyClass {
  run() {
    this.hello = 1;
    co(function*() {
      this.hello // this is now 'undefined'
    })
  }
}
new MyClass().run()
```

In ES5 I would normally assign `this` to another variable at the start of the function, such as `var cls = this`, but I would have hoped that ES6/ES7 would of solved this problem by now.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The `this` problem is solved by arrow functions, except that the arrow function syntax doesn't support generator. So either use `bind` or use `const` (instead of var).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
class MyClass {
  run() {
    this.hello = 1;
    co(function*() {
      this.hello // 1
    }.bind(this));
  }
}
new MyClass().run()
```

Comment: If I use `.bind()`, then how would I reference `co.this`?

Comment: @sleepycal `co`'s `this` is `global`, you don't need it. Usually `bind` is inappropriate with generator functions, but it is safe to use it with `co`.

Comment: @estus For libs other than `co`, is there a better way, or is re-assigning `cls = this` the standard?

Comment: @sleepycal Ideally, a good code shouldn't make a difference between generator and plain function, both can return iterables. Any way, there is a code that may rely on detecting them. I'm using a helper to bind them, `function genBind(fn, ctx) { let bound = fn.bind(ctx); Object.setPrototypeOf(bound, Object.getPrototypeOf(fn)); return bound; }`. For plain functions, look no further than `bind` and arrows.