# How to avoid creating references of 'this' in ES6: const that = this when scope nested in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, ecmascript-6, scope

I am reading the air-bnb javascript style guide and it says this should not be done:

23.5 Don’t save references to this. Use arrow functions or Function#bind.

```
// bad
function foo() {
  const self = this;
  return function () {
    console.log(self);
  };
}

// bad
function foo() {
  const that = this;
  return function () {
    console.log(that);
  };
}

// good
function foo() {
  return () => {
    console.log(this);
  };
}
```

I already did some research and found two answers here in stackoverflow but the accepted answer in one of them is that this cannot be circumvented:

[ES6 avoid that/self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660534/es6-avoid-that-self)

and the other one suggests using bind, but it suggested using a generator function.

[Nested reference to `this` in ES6 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458925/nested-reference-to-this-in-es6-classes)

I am building a ReactJS app and I need to access setState from within a firebase Promise.

```
   saveSessionToDB = () => {
        const that = this;
        db.collection("sessions")
          .add({
            props: MyProps
          })
          .then(function(docRef) {
            console.log("Session written with ID: ", docRef.id);
            that.setState({ sessionID: docRef.id });
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
            that.setState({ sessionError: error });
          });
}
```

I tried

```
const {setState} = this;
```

and then

```
setState({sessionID:docRef.id});
```

but I get an error.

I tried binding the saveSessionToDB in the constructor to no avail, even if it's an arrow function.

Is there another way of doing this or should I just accept that sometimes I will have to still write const that = this?

Comment: Why don't you just use arrow functions?

Comment: You might remind them of [*Hitchens's razor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitchens%27s_razor). *Why* is it bad?

Comment: @ritaj it is an arrow function.

Comment: @RobG pretty much all of the ESLint rules don't have "proof" of being bad but are mostly coding standards. It's good to keep them, bad to deviate, even if you can achieve the same thing with different code/syntax/formatting.

Comment: @guergana not what you pass to `.then`

Comment: `.then(function(docRef) {} )` this is not an arrow function.

Comment: yes, just noticed. thanks!

Comment: @VLAZ—yes they do, see the [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/). ESLint doesn't prescribe what's "good" or "bad", it's just a bunch of rules that can be used for checking coding style, i.e. just because it has a rule doesn't mean enforcing that rule is a good idea in general. The documentation includes suggestions of when not to use particular rules (e.g. [*no-invalid-this*](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-invalid-this)).

Comment: @RobG that is...what I said. ESLint rules is just for enforcing coding standards. Ergo, aren't "good" or "bad".

Comment: @VLAZ—sure, missed your point. :-) But it reinforces that Airbnb should explain why *that* and *self* should not be used (I really don't care, I just think they should explain why they insist on a particular coding style).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use arrow functions for the `then` and `catch` too:

```
saveSessionToDB = () => {
  db.collection("sessions")
    .add({ props: MyProps })
    .then((docRef) => {
      console.log("Session written with ID: ", docRef.id);
      this.setState({ sessionID: docRef.id });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
      this.setState({ sessionError: error });
    });
}
```

The reason why arrow functions are useful is that they don't have a `this` context of their own (or an `arguments`), so they adopt the `this` from their outer lexical environment. Which is why you can use the component's `this` inside the arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow functions for the internal functions:

```
.then(docRef => {
  console.log("Session written with ID: ", docRef.id);
  this.setState({ sessionID: docRef.id });
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
  this.setState({ sessionError: error });
});
```

Or use `bind`:

```
.then(function(docRef) {
  console.log("Session written with ID: ", docRef.id);
  that.setState({ sessionID: docRef.id });
}.bind(this))
.catch(function(error) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
  that.setState({ sessionError: error });
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

In promises that are used on screens/components and even, mostly outside of react syntax in the then() method and catch() you usually send an arrow function (There is nothing worth in the fetch context) so you keep the context from outside (In this case the React.Component context).

In your case with just two fixes (arrow function, and that to this) everything works:

```
saveSessionToDB = () => {
        const that = this;
        db.collection("sessions")
          .add({
            props: MyProps
          })
          .then((docRef) => { // arrow function
            console.log("Session written with ID: ", docRef.id);
            this.setState({ sessionID: docRef.id }); // that => this
          })
          .catch((error) => { // arrow function
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
            this.setState({ sessionError: error }); // that => this
          });
}
```